# Выполняется старая версия кода

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Установил Visual Studio 2015. Создал проект. написал простую программу из разряда "привет мир". В какой то момент перестает компилироваться программа, то есть меняю реплику на "мир привет", а выдается "привет мир". То есть старый exe файл запускается. Кто подскажет как побороть?

Comment: Добавьте в свой вопрос пример кода. У вас студия на английском или на русском языке?

Comment: Студия на английском.

Comment: пример кода можно он тривиален вывести на экраннадпись.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Причина запуска старого варианта кода может быть в том, что новый код содержит ошибки и согласно настройкам среды производится запуск последней удачной сборки.

Проверьте настройки на странице <kbd>Tools</kbd> - <kbd>Options</kbd> - <kbd>Projects & Solutions</kbd> - <kbd>Build & Run</kbd>:

[image: опции]

Comment: Не помогло. Стал говорить что нет доступа к файлу Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Users\"сокращено"\Debug\prog.exe'

Comment: @Vladimir может у Вас процесс висит уже в списке запущенных? Это не позволяет перезаписать `.exe` новым файлом.

Comment: Большое спасибо я что то  не додумался про это